# Undergraduate research on statistics as a 1st year

Tags: research-undergraduate, statistics

I'm in the 1st year of a 4 year bachelor's degree, majoring in statistics. I'm interested in probability theory and want to start research or any kind of research project. I know very little: just classical, conditional and Random variables. How can I start research? How can I approach a professor for guidance?

Comment: welcome to the site. You have several questions as part of your question. The first question has several similar questions on this stie. The topic of research are off topic here and what you should learn is off topic because it depends upon you.

Comment: Thank you sir.I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to any of your math or statistics professors who you admire and who you are doing well with. This year or maybe next. It is a bit early to be very specific about research at this point as you have a lot of basics to learn and the "research frontier" is a long way from the basics.

But letting one or two professors know of your long term plans and that you are looking for guidance in following it is worth doing. Perhaps at some point they might have some project for you, but work on your courses and seek insight into why things are true as well as what is true and false.

It might take you years to reach the research frontier and some parts of the journey are hard. But it is good to start and to have a guide or two.